# why extend a python list

Tags: python, list, merge, append, extend

Why use extend when you can just use the += operator? Which method is best?
Also what's the best way of joining multiple lists into one list

```
#my prefered way
_list=[1,2,3]
_list+=[4,5,6]
print _list
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

#why use extend:
_list=[1,2,3]
_list.extend([4,5,6])
print _list
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]



_lists=[range(3*i,3*i+3) for i in range(3)]
#[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]

#my prefered way of merging lists
print sum(_lists,[])
#[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]


#is there a better way?
from itertools import chain
print list(chain(*_lists))
#[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`+=` can only be used to extend one list by **another list**, while `extend` can be used to extend one list by **an iterable object**

e.g.

you can do

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.extend(set([4,5,6]))
```

but you can't do

```
a = [1,2,3]
a += set([4,5,6])
```

For the second question

```
[item for sublist in l for item in sublist] is faster.
```

see [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: Thanks! That pretty much nails it. Is _list+=list(_iterable) equivalent?

Comment: The can achieve the same result, but the underlying implementation will be different.

Answer (score 1):

You may `extend()` a python list with a non-list object as an iterator. An iterator is not storing any value, but an object to iterate once over some values. More on iterators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained).

In this thread, there are examples where an iterator is used as an argument of `extend()` method: [append vs. extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend/16510635#16510635)